# How to use XSL to dynamically set an attribute value

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt

I'm new to xslt and i'm doing a chat application and I want to save the users sessions as xml files that appear with the user predefined color and font so I used xslt to make that happen but I don't know how to take the font from the xml and applay it in the html tag so it appears with the font that the user selected.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="/body/msg[italic/text()='true']">
        <i>
            <font family="/body/msg[font/text()] color="/body/msg/color">
                <xsl:value-of select="from" /><p>: </p>
                <xsl:value-of select="content"/><br/>
            </font>
        </i>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="/body/msg[bold/text()='true']">
        <b>
            <font family="/body/msg[font/text()]" color="/body/msg/color">
                <xsl:value-of select="from" /><p>: </p>
                <xsl:value-of select="content"/><br/>
            </font>
        </b>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="/body/msg[bold/text()='true'] and /body/msg[italic/text()='true']">
        <b>
            <i>
                <font family="/body/msg[font/text()]" color="/body/msg/color">
                    <xsl:value-of select="from" /><p>: </p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="content"/><br/>
                </font>
            </i>
        </b>
    </xsl:when> 
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: using XSLT to generate presentation conscious HTML is going to leave you very much alone.  If you're looking to generate user selectable themes, you should be using CSS, either generated from XSLT with consistent markup or using predefined classes in an external file which are attached through the transform.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to guess without seeing your input format, however I think you are looking for attribute value templates  (Using `{ }` in literal result element attribute values). If you change

```
 <font family="/body/msg[font/text()]" color="/body/msg/color">
```

to

```
 <font family="{/body/msg[font/text()]}" color="{/body/msg/color}">
```

Then the `family` and `color` attributes will get values by evaluating those XPaths, although the Xpath for family looks very suspect. The above would give the string value of the whole msg element, I suspect it should be more like `/body/msg/font`  To extract the string value of the font element. (It's usually best to avoid using `text()` if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Could I propose using an approach like this?  When possible, it's a good idea to avoid repeating large parts of your code (this is known as the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), and with the following, if you need to make a change to that `<font>` portion and the stuff inside it, you don't have to change it in three places.  This also handles the case where neither `bold` nor `italic` are specified, which yours doesn't currently take into account:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="msg" />
    </body>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="msg">
    <xsl:param name="formatting" select="bold | italic"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$formatting[self::bold and . = 'true']">
        <b>
          <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
            <xsl:with-param name="formatting" select="$formatting[not(self::bold)]" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </b>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$formatting[self::italic and . = 'true']">
        <i>
          <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
            <xsl:with-param name="formatting" select="$formatting[not(self::italic)]" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </i>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <font family="{font}" color="{color}">
          <xsl:value-of select="from" />
          <p>: </p>
          <xsl:value-of select="content"/>
          <br/>
        </font>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on this input:

```
<root>
  <body>
    <msg>
      <bold>true</bold>
      <italic>false</italic>
      <font>Arial</font>
      <color>Blue</color>
      <from>Shelly</from>
      <content>Hey, how are you doing?</content>
    </msg>
    <msg>
      <bold>false</bold>
      <italic>true</italic>
      <font>Times New Roman</font>
      <color>Red</color>
      <from>Tom</from>
      <content>What's up?</content>
    </msg>
    <msg>
      <bold>false</bold>
      <italic>false</italic>
      <font>Courier</font>
      <color>Yellow</color>
      <from>Fred</from>
      <content>I've been trying to reach you</content>
    </msg>
    <msg>
      <bold>true</bold>
      <italic>true</italic>
      <font>Comic Sans</font>
      <color>Green</color>
      <from>Lisa</from>
      <content>Talk to you later.</content>
    </msg>
  </body>
</root>
```

Produces:

```
<body>
  <b>
    <font family="Arial" color="Blue">
      Shelly<p>: </p>Hey, how are you doing?<br />
    </font>
  </b>
  <i>
    <font family="Times New Roman" color="Red">
      Tom<p>: </p>What's up?<br />
    </font>
  </i>
  <font family="Courier" color="Yellow">
    Fred<p>: </p>I've been trying to reach you<br />
  </font>
  <b>
    <i>
      <font family="Comic Sans" color="Green">
        Lisa<p>: </p>Talk to you later.<br />
      </font>
    </i>
  </b>
</body>
```